# Apache FOP - include one xsl to another

Tags: pdf, xslt, include, apache-fop

I have many XSL files, which have one common part. I want to separate this part to another XSL file and include it to every file (to be able to apply changes to it only once). I am using Apache FOP to create PDF from the XSL file. I already tried the approach described here: [How to use `xsl:include` with apache fop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22638290/how-to-use-xslinclude-with-apache-fop), but no success.

Here is part of the XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="fooBar">
   <fo:root xmlns:fo="__http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
       <fo:layout-master-set>
....
.... 

<!-- Parent element of the part, I want to separate -->
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="pages">

<!-- This is the part, I want to move to separate XSL file -->
<fo:static-content flow-name="page-footer">
    <fo:block font-size="7pt" margin-left="10mm">
      <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" border-collapse="separate">
      <fo:table-column column-width="100%"/>
        <fo:table-body>
        <fo:table-row>
          <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block>Some text which will be changed</fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
      </fo:table-body>
     </fo:table>
   </fo:block>
</fo:static-content>
<!-- This is the part, I want to move to separate XSL file -->
```

When I place the part to separate XSL file, I get this errors, by Apache FOP.

SystemId Unknown; (line and column of the include); org.xml.sax.SAXException: ElemTemplateElement error: "template name"
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: ElemTemplateElement error: "template name"
SystemId Unknown; (line and column of the include); Could not find template named: "template name"

I tried this ways of the include:

```
<xsl:include href="templateFileName.xsl"/> (To the header)
<xsl:call-template name="templateFileName"/> (Directly on wanted place)
<xsl:apply-templates select="templateFileName"/> (Directly on wanted place)
```

None of them worked.

The PDF is created, but without this part. I will gladly provide more info/details, if needed.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Your three _"ways of the include"_ are actually quite different things, and a single one of it will not be enough; as explained in the question you linked, you have to (1) create a named template in an external file, (2) include in in the "main" stylesheet, and (3) call the named template where you want the content to be created.

Comment: I have the same question, and all I've been able to determine so far is that it works when you provide the full path, e.g., <xsl:include href="C:/path/to/file.xsl"/>